# How can I cancel reading a file into a buffer on BufReadPre?

Tags: autocmd

In order to open PDFs using an external application, one can use the following script:

```
augroup nonvim
   au!
   au BufRead *.pdf sil exe "!open " . shellescape(expand("<afile>")) | bd  
augroup end
```

However, this is not optimal, because the pdf would still be loaded into vim, which will take a while if it is large. More importantly, your window layout will be messed up if you have more than one window showing, because of `bd`.

So, I thought of using `BufReadPre` instead of using `BufRead`. This way, I may still be able to cancel reading the file into a buffer. The question is: how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better option would be [`BufReadCmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufReadCmd):

```
                                                        BufReadCmd
BufReadCmd                      Before starting to edit a new buffer.  Should
                                read the file into the buffer. Cmd-event
```

Since this is supposed to read the file into the buffer, you can just *not* read it. :)

If you try to do a `bd` in a `BufReadPre` `autocmd`, you'll get an error:

```
E201: *ReadPre autocommands must not change current buffer
```

With `BufReadCmd`:

```
augroup nonvim
   au!
   au BufReadCmd *.pdf sil exe '!open' shellescape(expand("<afile>")) | bd
augroup end
```

I don't use a Mac, but replacing `open` with [`xdg-open`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html), it worked fairly well enough.

Comment: @ultrabowser O.o the advantage of using `BufReadCmd` is that you **aren't** reading the file in Vim.

Comment: @ultrabowser Yes. Vim opens an empty buffer, and then this autocmd is supposed to read the contents of the file. Instead, we just call `open`, and skip reading the file, and delete the now unnecessary buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Building on muru's answer, here  is a solution that makes opening PDF files through vim seamless. The problem with `:bd` is that it messes up the window layout, but aside from that you may end up at a completely different buffer than where you opened the PDF from. This uses `:b#` and then deletes the empty buffer.

One last annoyance - that the buffer is centerd on re-entry - can be fixed with [this script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_scrolling_when_switch_buffers). (Use the original version or remove the check for `atStartOfFile`.)

```
augroup nonvim
   au!
   au BufReadCmd *.pdf sil exe "!xdg-open " . shellescape(expand("<afile>")) . "&>/dev/null" |
       \ let tobedeleted = bufnr('%') | b# | exe "bd! " . tobedeleted
augroup end
```

Works with NERDtree.